# python socket, получить все данные посредством recv()

Tags: python, сокет, tcp

Хочу забрать контент посредством GET-запроса через socket, уже день как застрял на этой проблеме. Не для кого наверное не секрет, что recv(x) с любым количеством x байт вернет только часть данных.

```
    try:
        sock.connect((host_ip, 80))
        sock.send('GET / HTTP/1.1' + "\n" + "HOST: " + host + "\n\n")
        res_data = sock.recv(65000)
    except socket.error, e:
        console.err("can't connect: " + os.strerror(e.errno))
    else:
        self.data = res_data.decode("utf-8")
```

Первое, что приходит на ум - рекурсивный цикл, который вытащил бы все данные:

```
        res_data = ''
        while True:
            data = sock.recv(65000)
            if not data:
                break
            res_data += data
```

Программа благополучно зависает. Находил всяческие решения через timeout, мол ожидать несколько миллисекунд с каждым шагом, потому как это не текст, и данные могут не приходить периодически - тоже ничего не вышло (

i need help!

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python socket client Post parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28670835/4279)

Comment: в сторону: вместо *"рекурсивный цикл"* используйте просто "цикл". Слово рекурсия в Питоне подразумевает вызов функции самой себя (возможно неявно), например: `qsort = lambda L: qsort([x for x in L[1:] if x <= L[0]]) + [L[0]] + qsort([x for x in L if x > L[0]]) if L else L`

Comment: Хоть с циклом, хоть с `Content-Length`, хоть с `Connection: close` — всё равно обломаетесь об `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. Если это всё не в образовательных целях, лучше взять какую-нибудь готовую http-библиотеку

Comment: @andreymal: если `Connection: close` используется, то код в вопросе получит *все* данные без зависания. Верно, что любой http/1.1 клиент обязан понимать `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, но она задумана, чтобы позволить поддерживать постоянные подключения, если сервер знает что данный запрос имеет `Connection: close`, то меньше оснований `chunked` кодировку использовать. Верно, что полноценный http клиент ещё тучу вещей должен делать и что по умолчанию следует что-нибудь вроде `requests` использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http/1.1 клиенты, которые не поддерживают постоянное подключение (как код в вопросе), обязаны посылать `Connection: close` заголовок (RFC 2616 14.10):

> HTTP/1.1 applications that do not support persistent connections MUST
>   include the "close" connection option in every message.

Вот [пример кода, который выполняет POST https запрос, используя socket напрямую](https://gist.github.com/zed/1841962#file-http-post-socket-py).

Comment: jfs, большое Вам спасибо! Добавив этот заголовок, рекурсивно получил все данные страницы до '</body></html>'